# append substitute to concat?

Tags: pandas, append, concatenation

i want to fill my dataframe using 'append' method, but i got warning that the 'append' is depreciated, i tried to use concat but i can't get same result

```
my_columns = ['a', 'b','c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)
df = df.append(pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 'n/a'], index = my_columns), ignore_index = True)
```

FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version.

```
desired ouput =

    a   b   c   d
0   10  20  30  n/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series is a one-dimensional array with axis labels, so you will not be able to get that desired output using pd.Series.

Im assuming if you have a dataframe consisting of information that you want to append to another, you can simply use:

```
cols = ['a','b','c','d']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30,'n/a']],columns=cols)],axis=0)

print(df)
```

Make sure the data is in a list within a list to indicate it is a row you are appending.

Output:

```
    a   b   c    d
0  10  20  30  n/a
```

Comment: Thank you, if you could upvote, that would be brilliant :)

Comment: Many Thank thmasxx, it really helpful.. I understand the logic now.

Comment: will upvote soon.. I need 15 reputation at least